# Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') at calculateBmi at onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

`Hi guys, I am trying to create a BMI calculator. Below is my code but when I do the onclick calling a function I am getting error. However, I checked by doing an alert and the alert did workout. I think there is something error which I do not understand. Please help!!`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss3ix.jpg)

`I did alert in function just to check and looking for a solution to surpass this error`

Comment: One or more of your querySelector patterns is wrong.  If you want to select an element by id it needs to start with `#`  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors

Comment: Translate this answer [Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML') at calculateBmi at onclick](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o) into (from ru) your language and I think you will be able to understand why an error occurs in your code

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Balaji, welcome to stack Overflow. I'm glad that you are willing to learn JavaScript. Before asking on stack Overflow, you should look for documentation and try to figure things out by yourself which is going to be beneficial for you in learning this correctly. The solution to your problem is:

```
function calculateBmi(){

let weight = document.getElementById('weight').value
let height = document.getElementById('height').value

 let bmi = (weight/ (height * height)* 703)

 document.querySelector('#heading').innerHTML ="Your BMI is: "
 document.querySelector('#bmi-output').innerHTML = bmi
 }

 function refreshPage(){
 window.location.reload()
 }
```

So, the problem with your code was with the `querySelector`
see: [this website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)

Comment: How do you know that bmi-output isn't a class rather than an id for example - given you have not seen the HTML? Your answer may be right, but it may be wrong.

Comment: @AHaworth that's why I have included the link to Mozilla docs!!